# How to dockerize PDI jobs with postgres?

Tags: docker, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration, docker-build

I am trying to dockerize pdi server but I am unable to run jobs with postgres in docker.

Comment: Hi, can you provide us with your current work result? Do you have a dockerfile that you use? Do you use the official postgres image available at dockerhub? If so which version? What is a PDI server? Can you point us to a website for that product?

Comment: @ClemensKaserer I am following this article https://github.com/andrespp/docker-pdi     and i am able to run normal jobs i.e without postgres.The version of pdi PDI_VERSION=8.3 PDI_BUILD=8.3.0.0-371, and for postgres, i am using docker image of postgres itself.